# Are there any helicopters equipped with pressurized cabins?

Tags: helicopter

I would think that a pressurized helicopter is impractical since helicopters are usually flying at low altitude, but has a pressurized helicopter ever been conceived or built?

Comment: Bell Helicopter BA609

Comment: @Energizer777 Strictly speaking, the Bell 609 (now [Agusta Westland AW609](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgustaWestland_AW609)) is a _tilt-rotor_ similar to the V22 Osprey. It hasn't yet been certified or entered production

Comment: An unmodified helicopter with a gas turbine engine landed on the summit of Mount Everest in 2005. It was a Eurocopter AS350 B3. AFAIK the pilot used oxygen, and the helicopter was not pressurized.

Comment: The weight and the price would need to be justified by some high altitude mission for which an O2 mask is not appropriate. What could that be, given the low ceiling of such aircraft? Imagine an airplane pressurized door. A loss of pressure could occur instantly due to the small volume, that's another show stopper.

Answer (score 12):

Helicopter cabins are not usually pressurized as they are not expected to be operated at high altitudes.

The largest operational helicopter, the [Mil Mi 26 Halo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-26) has a pressurized crew cabin.

The Russian [Mil Mi-24 Hind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-24) and [Mil Mi 28 Havoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-28) feature pressurized cockpits. However, these are for operating in an NBC environment, not for high altitude operation.

Comment: What is an NBC environment?

Comment: @RyanBurnette Nuclear, Biological and Chemical- A condition where there is a possibility of contamination due to radiological, biological or chemical agents, usually in war.

Comment: Is that a small overpressure with free (uncontrolled) release of the air in excess, or a fully airtight system?

Comment: @mins It is of the overpressure type, atleast in the combat helicopters.